# TPL on List filled with Store

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I can't get the following to work

```
{[displayDate(dateRelease);]}
```

Each model from the store has the property "dateRelease"

I need to get that date and transform it with my displayDate() before displaying it.

When I write the code, I get the error that dateRelease is not found.

How should I proceed?

Comment: try putting it in quotes :) like {[displayDate("dateRelease");]}

Comment: Try using `values.dateRelease`

Comment: Nah it did not work since it created the string dateRelease and not the value that I try to retrieve.

Comment: post values.dateRelease it worked! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `values.dateRelease`.

Comment: Would you happen to know some kind of tutorial to understand what is going on in TPL, it kinds of bugs me how different it is from everything else.

Comment: The docs have actually improved quite a bit on this, and offer a lot of good info: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate.  Other than that, most of the knowledge I've gained is from trial and error. :-/

Comment: I guess I should have known that the doc would not be Sencha touch's but ExtJS... They really don't care about their doc at all

Comment: @Fawar, if this is for Touch you will also want to check their docs for XTemplate: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate.  There are actually a few things missing from Touch that ExtJS has, like the for-each loops.

Comment: I'm getting used to the "missing part", "missing doc", "wrong doc, wrong implementation", brag for a feature and end up unusuable XD

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589176/how-to-call-functions-within-a-xtemplate-itemtpl).

For your example it would look like:

```
itemTpl: new XTemplate(
    '<tpl>',
        '<p>{[this.displayDate(dateRelease)]}</p>',
    '</tpl>',
    {        
        displayDate: function(date){
            return runFunction(date);
        }
    }
);
```

I have not tested this syntax so there may be a typo.

Comment: I saw this thread, problem is using Sencha Architect, I may not write the 2nd part { displayDate : ....} has the field I get is put directly  where your <tpl></tpl> tags are :S