# Sencha Touch 2 - embed a Component with xtype in items but not work

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Lately im trying to learn ST2 myself, and then bug things happend.
I create a Ext.Component view, and then i put it to a parent view which extends Ext.Container.
Unfortunately, there is nothing but air rendered in my page. Some guys help me ? Much thanx. Here is my CODES below.

---

### app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'myAPP',

    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox'
    ],

    models: [
        'Goods'
    ],

    views: [
        'Viewport',
        'GoodsList',
        'GoodsListItem'
    ],

    controllers: [],

    stores: [
        'GoodsList'
    ],
    // some basic codes...
});
```

### Viewport.js - view

```
Ext.define('myAPP.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

    xtype: 'viewport',

    config: {
        fullscreen: true,

        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        defaults: {
            styleHtmlContent: true
        },

        items: [
            {
                title: 'Series',
                iconCls: 'list',
                xtype: 'goodslist'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

### GoodsList.js - view

```
Ext.define('myAPP.view.GoodsList', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'myAPP.view.GoodsListItem'
    ],

    xtype: 'goodslist',

    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'fit'
        },

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',

                title: 'GoodsList',

                docked: 'top',

                items: [
                    {
                        iconCls: 'more',
                        align: 'right'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'goodslistitem'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

### GoodsListItem.js - view

```
Ext.define('myAPP.view.GoodsListItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',

    xtype: 'goodslistitem',

    config: {
        store: 'goodsliststore',

        tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for=".">',
                '<div class="s-row">',
                    '<div class="s-col {[xindex % 2 === 0 ? "s-c2" : "s-c1"]}">',
                        '<img src="{thumb}" />',
                        '<h1>{#}. {pname}</h1>',
                        '{price}',
                    '</div>',
                '</div>',
            '</tpl>'
        )
    }
});
```

### GoodsList.js - store

```
Ext.define('myAPP.store.GoodsList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model: 'myAPP.model.Goods',

        storeId: 'goodsliststore',

        data: [
            {
                pname: 'Goods',
                price: '5RMB',
                thumb: 'http://qlogo4.store.qq.com/qzone/181830631/181830631/100?1317298327'
            },
            {
                pname: 'Goods',
                price: '15RMB',
                thumb: 'http://qlogo4.store.qq.com/qzone/181830631/181830631/100?1317298327'
            },
            {
                pname: 'Goods',
                price: '25RMB',
                thumb: 'http://qlogo4.store.qq.com/qzone/181830631/181830631/100?1317298327'
            },
            {
                pname: 'Goods',
                price: '35RMB',
                thumb: 'http://qlogo4.store.qq.com/qzone/181830631/181830631/100?1317298327'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

### Goods.js - model

```
Ext.define('myAPP.model.Goods', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'pname', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'price', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'thumb', type: 'string' }
        ]
    }
});
```

---

**ST Version - Touch 2.1.1**

Comment: ... what should be the result?

Comment: @NicoGrunfeld, hi, i just want show a list on my page, as you see, the results should be displayed with the tpl's data in **GoodsListItem.js - view**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are missing some of the basics concepts for working with lists in Sencha Touch.

Your GoodsList view doesn't actually have an [Ext.dataview.List](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List), so that's why you don't see anything.
Replace the element:

```
{
    xtype: 'goodslistitem'
}
```

with a list component, something like:

```
{
    xtype: 'list'
}
```

Now let's put it fullscreen and let's use the [XTemplate](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate) you defined in `GoodsListItem.js` as the [itemTpl](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-defaultType) for your list:

```
{
    xtype: 'list',
    fullscreen: true,
    itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="s-row">',
                '<div class="s-col {[xindex % 2 === 0 ? "s-c2" : "s-c1"]}">',
                    '<img src="{thumb}" />',
                    '<h1>{#}. {pname}</h1>',
                    '{price}',
                '</div>',
            '</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    )

}
```

You can actually delete your GoodsListItem.js view.
If you really want to go with a separate list item that can use components layout, you should set the [defaultType](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-defaultType) configuration, but this has worse performance and adds a level of complexity. Check the guide on [Using Dataviews](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/dataview) if you are interested.

Note: I am assuming your `Ext.XTemplate` syntax is correct.

[EDIT] My code probably won't work as it is: check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589176/how-to-call-functions-within-a-xtemplate-itemtpl) about using XTemplate as itemTpl

Last we have to say Sencha Touch which Store to bind to the list, this is done through the store configuration:

```
{
    xtype: 'list',
    fullscreen: true,
    itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="s-row">',
                '<div class="s-col {[xindex % 2 === 0 ? "s-c2" : "s-c1"]}">',
                    '<img src="{thumb}" />',
                    '<h1>{#}. {pname}</h1>',
                    '{price}',
                '</div>',
            '</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ),
    store: 'GoodsList'
}
```

This should point you on the right track. If you ask me, you are trying to accomplish something quite complex from scratch, I would suggest you to make your way to this starting with a basic list example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    fullscreen: true,
    itemTpl: '{title}',
    data: [
        { title: 'Item 1' },
        { title: 'Item 2' },
        { title: 'Item 3' },
        { title: 'Item 4' }
    ]
});
```

Then adding in steps more complex stuff, like binding to an `Ext.data.Store`, using an `Ext.Template` as itemTpl, then an `Ext.XTemplate`

Comment: **Thanx** @Andrea, i accepted your suggest and i use itemTpl with Ext.DataView to fix my wrong codes. And in the end, i style my list with baseCls, finally, it shows the right UI that i want.

Comment: @Soon Please read this page about accepting answers: http://stackoverflow.com/about on how this site works.